# CSS changing a previous radio button selection when should not

Tags: html, css

I have this code with a 5 star rating(radio button) to be used in two different questions.

The problem is: the ratings  of each question are working as one. I mean, I select something in the first question, but when I do a selection in the second question it changes the selection in the first one.

This problem happens when I add the CSS code. Without the CSS it works fine.

What is wrong in the CSS?

```css
.estrelas input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}

.estrelas label i.fa:before {
  content: '\f005';
  color: #FC0;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.estrelas input[type=radio]:checked~label i.fa:before {
  color: #CCC;
}

.estrelas {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">ASPECTOS FORMAIS/GRAMATICAIS</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 estrelas" id="pergunta_1">
    <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="pergunta_1" value=1_1 />
    <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="pergunta_1" value=1_2 />
    <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="pergunta_1" value=1_3 />
    <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="pergunta_1" value=1_4 />
    <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="pergunta_1" value=1_5 />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group has-feedback">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <label for="co_pergunta_avaliacao" class="control-label">CONTE&#218;DO/ARGUMENTA&#199;&#195;O</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-8 estrelas" id="pergunta_2">
    <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="pergunta_2" value=2_1 />
    <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="pergunta_2" value=2_2 />
    <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="pergunta_2" value=2_3 />
    <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="pergunta_2" value=2_4 />
    <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="pergunta_2" value=2_5 />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs. If it is not unique, it is no longer an ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio button IDs must be unique. Here, IDs `cm_star-1` ... `cm_star-5` are used for 2 radio buttons each, which causes the behavior.